# Why are fuses used for appliances that are plugged into the wall socket?

Tags: current, fuses

Fuses are there to ensure that the device being used doesn't short circuit and overheat.

How likely is it that the current from a wall socket will actually exceed its given amount of current of, for example, 10 A?

Answer (score 4):

A fuse can't prevent a device from short-circuiting. The purpose of a fuse is mostly to safeguard a cable, and also to stop current flowing through a faulty device and possibly do more damage.

Your mains may have 10 A or 16 A or some-other-value fuses (depending on where you live and how old your house is), but the device connected to the mains, and its cable, may be specified for a much smaller current, so you still need lower-value (and maybe faster) fuses to protect cable and device.

The cable of such a device will overheat (and possibly cause a fire) long before the mains' fuses react, if they react at all.

Answer (score 3):

Some jurisdictions use a ring main (UK) which can supply 32A - so several devices can be used simultaneously on that main.

So, each device has a fuse, in the plug and often in the device as well. Fuses in the plug can be chosen to match the device so 3A, 5A or 13A (the max), while the fuses in the device can be fast acting and different ratings depending on what the device does.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit breaker in the house is there to prevent the wires in the walls from catching fire.  If something short circuits the wiring, the circuit breaker will shut off the current so that the wires in the walls don't get hot and catch fire.

The fuse is there to prevent your device from catching fire.  If something in the device draws more current than it should, the fuse blows and shuts off the current.

How much current it takes to cause a fire depends on the materials and the physical shapes and positions of the conductors.  A fire can start from relatively little current.

---

The current from a wall socket is only limited by the circuit breaker.  There is no other limit.  The wires in the walls are connected to the main house wiring through the circuit breaker.  If the circuit breaker were not there, then the outlets would (try) to deliver as much current as the connected device will draw.  You could short circuit an outlet and get as much current as the power lines to the house will deliver.

Comment: Very good except for a big mistake :-) It's not to prevent the cables catching fire - they won't ignite and catch fire, they'll simply melt through in one spot and scorch/melt away that one patch of insulation. Downvoting accordingly. Will upvote and delete this comment if that's corrected and catching fire is removed altogether. As an aside, there's no mention of earth leakage detection, which a sentence on would round the answer better but that's just opinion.

Comment: @TonyM I disagree. It's quite possible for overheating cables to start a fire, even if they don't self-ignite they're likely to be running over carpet, under curtains or other soft furnishings which could. Maybe "causing fire" would be more accurate than "catching fire".

Comment: @Finbarr, you're changing it to something very different. The answer says 'in the walls' and that's all I'm commenting on, please let's keep focused.

Comment: @TonyM Many houses have walls made of wood, or at least have cables running through wooden studding faced with plasterboard. Overheating cables are quite capable of starting fires inside such walls as well as outside.

Comment: @Finbarr, that and those were not my point and I disagree. But I've stated my case so if you'd to go into anything further, please take it to chat to avoid (this) extended comment discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Devices are fused because if they malfunction and consume much larger current than intended, the fuse will blow to cut power.

If you have 10A breakers/fuses in your apartment, that's what is available from the socket then. You really don't want say a malfunctioning toothbrush or phone  charger to draw 9A, which is not enough to trip the breaker. So the charger can overheat, melt and catch fire. Which is why the devices might have 0.5A fuse in them which will blow when they malfunction and current exceeds safe limits.